# Getting Player Profile from Get Params

Tags: python

I'm trying to put together a Python project where I have a main handler that receives GET parameters and based on the type of player is accessed will retrieve special data about the type of player they are.

So when it gets to the player_profile page it will retrieve data from a data.py file of that specific player depending on if they type is a pitcher or fielder.

```
import webapp2
from pages import Page, ContentPage

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        page = Page()
        content = ContentPage()

        if self.request.GET:
            type = self.request.GET['type']
            page.body = content.player_profile(type)
        else:
            page.body = content.home()
        self.response.write(page.print_out())

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)


class Page(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def print_out(self):
        all = self.head + self.header + self.container_open + self.sidebar + self.section_open + self.body + self.section_close + self.container_close + self.footer + self.close
        all = all.format(**locals())
        return all


class ContentPage(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def player_profile(self, type):
        return type

    def team_info(self):
        pass

    def home(self):

        pass
```

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: What would I have to do to be able to access certain player data that might be stored in the data.py file.